# How to portray this mathematically?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There is this shortcut to multiplication that I came across

96 x 97

can be solved by

(100 - 4) * (100 - 3)

multiply 4 and 3 we get **12**

Subtract 4+3 from 100 we get **93**

line it up = **9312**

What is the mathematical or number  theory representation for this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the high school identities:
$$(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab.$$

Answer (score 0):

The general formula is derived as follows:
\begin{align}
(100 - a) \times (100 - b) &= 100^2 - 100 a - 100 b + ab \\
&= 100(100 - (a + b)) + ab
\end{align}

If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $ab < 100$,
then the formula $100(100 - (a + b)) + ab$
can be calculated by taking the two digits of $100 - (a + b)$
and appending the two digits of $ab$ (or a zero and the single digit $ab$
if $ab < 10$).

Answer (score 0):

$$
(B-x)(B-y) = B^2 -B(x+y) + xy$$

Take $B=100$...

Comment: Possibly add that $B^2-B(x+y)=B(B-(x+y))$.